# Is there a name for the operands of union and intersection?

Tags: terminology

For subtraction, in $a - b$, we call $a$ the *minuend* and $b$ the *subtrahend*. With logical conjunction, $p \wedge q$, we can call $p$ and $q$ the *conjuncts*.

Are there terms like this for the operands of set union? Is there a term for $P$ and $Q$ in $P \cup Q$?

Likewise, are there terms for the operands of an intersection?

Answer (score 2):

The word *subtract* comes from the Latin verb [*subtrahō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/subtraho#Latin), whose conjugation gives *subtrahendus* as the future passive participle ('which is to be removed'), and thereby **subtrahend** in English. The English word **minuend** is likewise derived from the future passive participle (*minuendus*, 'which is to be made smaller') of [*minuō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/minuo#Latin). Similar derivations include:

- *integrō* > *integrandus* > **integrand**
- *sūmō* > *sūmendus* > **summand**
- *multiplicō* > *multiplicandus* > **multiplicand**

So following the same derivation:

- The word *intersect* coming from Latin verb [*intersecō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interseco#Verb_2), whose future passive participle is *intersecendus*, leading to **intersecend** (or more likely **intersecand**, to give a hard 'c').
- The word *union* comes from the Latin verb [*uniō*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unio#Verb), whose future passive participle is *ūniendus*, leading to **uniend** (or perhaps **uniand**).

That said, I have never seen the words intersecand or uniend, so using them will probably cause more confusion than it is worth.

...in fact, prior to reading your question, I had never heard the words minuend or subtrahend, either.

Answer (score 0):

How about "disjuncts" for $p \vee q$. And then just "conjuncts" and "disjuncts" again for $P \cap Q$ and $P \cup Q$ respectively (since those set theoretic operations are defined by applications of "and" and "or"). Sounds good to me, at least, although I've never even heard of "conjuncts".

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm thinking in German, but to me "disjuncts" sounds like it suggests the sets to be disjoint.

Comment: Just so you know I'm not making that up: Wikipedia uses both _conjunct_ and _disjunct_. [The Wikipedia site for conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction#Other_proof_strategies) has, for example, the sentence: "(...) a conjunction can actually be proven false just by knowing about the relation of its conjuncts and not necessary (sic) about their truth values." The [page for disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction) literally has the sentence: "An operand of a disjunction is called a disjunct."

Comment: Also, I think @MarsPlastic is right. Using _conjunct_ and _disjunct_ brings in the whole conceptual confusion that you get because a union actually conjoins the elements of the sets, but the union corresponds to the disjunction, etc. The equivalences are pretty straightforward, but at the same time very unintuitive.